# could not find class when class extends from LuminanceSource in android

Tags: android, zxing

I want to decode already saved bar-code image using zxing library.

Added external jar named "core.jar"

Created class MyLuminaceSource  which is subclass of LuminanceSource. Used this class to create Reader.

```
MyLuminaceSource myRGB = new MyLuminaceSource (barcodeImage);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(myRGB));
Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
String resulText =  result.getText();
```

But when i run app on device following error shows in logcat:

**"Could not find class 'com.....MyLuminaceSource', referenced from method com....MainActivity.decode"**

also throws run time exception when above code executes.

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved by making check enabled for external jar in "order and export" tab.

[image]